# why setState is not setting the state componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering why setState is not working for a specific property.

In my componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps), I'm setting the state for various state variables. But only one of them is not getting set. But, when I print the nextProps, I can clearly see the updated props for the specific state variable.

eg:

```
this.state = {
    job: { jobId: null, name: null},
    list: { items: null, total: null}
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// When I print nextProps, it is showing the updated prop value
    /* nextProps: {
                   job: 
                      {
                        jobId: 123, 
                        name: "sai"
                      }, 
                   list: 
                      {
                        items: 25, 
                        total: 150
                      }
                  }
      */

 this.setState({
      job: nextProps.job,
      list: nextProps.list
 });
 console.log(this.state.job); // gives me -> job: { jobId: null, name: null}
 console.log(this.state.list); // gives me -> list: { items: 25, total: 150}
}
```

When I print the output to console `this.state.job`, it is printing the initial state not the updated state. I'm not sure how to figure this out.

Comment: That’s because setState is asynchronous, you should try use the new syntax. `this.setState((prevState) => { return { job: nextProps.job, list: nextProps.list} });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the callback while you set state because `setState` is asynchronous and you will have to wait for the result until it finishes its job.

```
this.setState({
      job: nextProps.job,
      list: nextProps.list
 },function(){
  console.log(this.state) //here you will get updated values.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because setState works asynchronously and it hasn't finished setting the new state yet when you log it.

Try doing this an see the log

```
this.setState({
      job: nextProps.job,
      list: nextProps.list
 },()=>console.log(this.state);
```